# What happened to my comment?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

I have [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60027880/how-to-control-the-type-of-value-bound-using-ngmodel-number-gets-distorted-to-s/60027956#60027956) and made a comment to @robert as he made an excellent suggestion for a low-effort work-around which, although not totally best-practice, made my progress much less painful at that stage.

That comment seems to have disappeared and they never posted an actual answer, neither, which is a clear value loss in my opinion.

Can someone confirm what happened there?

More specifically, I have this worrying sensation that the user misunderstood my point, assumed that I was bashing him input, voted me down and left the discussion. That would be a terrible loss of positive feed-back, because he really saved my sitting device there.

Comment: No offence is taken from my side also I did not downvoted your question on stackoverflow nor reported your comment. In fact I read your comment here. The reason I posted as a comment is that at that time you already had an accepted answer.

Comment: @robert Good to hear. And it was only friendly meant. It's a great CSS-kung-foo trick and it saved my timeline. You should've seen the reaction. *How did you do that?!* Then I went, *oh, you know, just the usual stuff, nothing fancy, i just scootch this and hide that...* Of course, I later on explained where I got that from, hehe. I also still maintain that you should post it as an answer to preserve.

Answer (score 12):

Your comment was flagged as unfriendly, and I validated the flag by deleting your comment. Your comment was:

> Dude... Stop sneaking in goodies into comments. Take your stuff and post it as an answer. It's going to be awesomely upvoted. The answer below is the by-the-book but a bit heavy for noobs. Your suggestion is ugly AF but pragmatically working and on the highest tricky level. I want to see both as answers so people can pick, depending on the amount of time they have on their hands. Don't forget to snatch the code and not only post a link to the CSS-tricks.

I can understand what you wanted to convey, but the usage of words like "ugly AF" can be construed in the wrong way. I usually just edit out the wrong words (which in this case was possible), but given the fact that it just asks the user to post their comments as an answer, it would have been "no longer needed" soon after, therefore I just chose to delete it.

Comment: +1. I think "newbie" would have been more appropriate. "noob" is usually pejorative. Or as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newbie) puts it : `Different spellings can have quite different connotations; so in some contexts a "newb" refers to a beginner who is willing to learn; while a "noob", refers disparagingly to an inexperienced or under-talented hacker or gamer who lacks the determination to learn.`

Comment: @Konrad I would also suggest that your comment in the given answer, referring to *bovine testes* is also a bit near the edge.

Comment: The comment is a little risky but it also seems demanding and pointless given op can freely answer their own question. *"Take your stuff and post it as an answer. ...I want to see both as answers so people can pick, depending on the amount of time they have on their hands. Don't forget to snatch the code and not only post a link to the CSS-tricks."* Perhaps good intention and points but I wouldn't have appreciated the bossy tone.

Comment: @AdrianMole I had to google *bovine* to get your point. That was quite a sophisticated way to refer to my comment. Point taken. As I mention in the other comment, I see how my statement might be interpreted as hostile if the reader doesn't notice the underlying awe and praise by positive adjectives. The tone is rough but friendly. However, it's risky because some people might get the former and miss the latter.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Yupp, I can see how it can go sideways. Of course that's not the intended outcome but Tjernobyl '86 wasn't the intended outcome neither... I'll try to be more careful. Good point.